# Get followers' post along with own posts in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using neo4j for my social projects where User can create a post, and can follow each other. I have to fetch my follower' post along with my own post. To fetch my followers' post I am using the following query:

```
MATCH (me:User {UserId: '39434e4d-d501-4fba-8aae-16cf652deb3e'})-[:FOLLOWSS|CREATED]->(f:User)-(p:Posts) RETURN p LIMIT 25
```

above query returns my followers' post but I am unable to get my own post.
Can someone tell me what I am missing to get my own posts along with my followers' post

```
MATCH (me:User {UserId: '39434e4d-d501-4fba-8aae-16cf652deb3e'})-[:FOLLOWSS]->(f:User)-[fc:CREATED|LIKED]-(p:Posts)<-[:CREATED]-(n) RETURN p LIMIT 25
```

I tried above query but it doesn't return any records.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: small correction with existing query added created with follow

Comment: That won't work, unless it's possible for a user to create another user. You also don't have a relationship between `f` and `p` (you can use `--` between them for the presence of a relationship without a restriction on the type, though). It's better to use the optional relationship approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MATCH (me:User {UserId: '39434e4d-d501-4fba-8aae-16cf652deb3e'})-[:FOLLOWSS]->(f:User)-[fc:CREATED]-(p:Posts)<-[:CREATED]-(n) RETURN p LIMIT 25
```

is returning every post created by you AND someone else. You need to separate variables that are different items

```
MATCH (mine:Posts)<-[:CREATED]-(me:User {UserId: '39434e4d-d501-4fba-8aae-16cf652deb3e'})-[:FOLLOWSS]->(f:User)-[fc:CREATED]-(p:Posts) RETURN mine, p LIMIT 25
```

But, this returns info in a vary redundant way (Every your post against every their post), so I would recommend compressing it with COLLECT like this.

```
MATCH (mine:Posts)<-[:CREATED]-(me:User {UserId: '39434e4d-d501-4fba-8aae-16cf652deb3e'})-[:FOLLOWSS]->(f:User)-[fc:CREATED]-(p:Posts)
WITH mine, p LIMIT 25
WITH COLLECT(mine)+COLLECT(p) as posts
UNWIND posts as p
RETURN p LIMIT 25
```

Comment: I made a small correction with the existing query, sorry for inconvenience. I removed -[fc:CREATED]

Comment: @AmitSharma The change you made is minor and insignificant. This answer is meant to explain why your cypher logic is wrong, and how to fix that. InverseFalcon's answer is the most correct way to fix it. If between these two answers you can't solve your problem, we need more info on what is not working.

Comment: but it returns the duplicate of "mine", I want unique posts.

Comment: @AmitSharma "mine" is posts the user created, and "p" is posts followers created. Unless a post can be created by users and followers, there will be no duplicates between the two sets.

Comment: How can we apply the limit on the query as we are using an alias?

Comment: @AmitSharma I'm not sure what you mean? I modified the query slightly to use UNWIND to change the returned data to match the format of the original query. Is this what you mean?

Comment: how can we add some additional custom fields like total share count or total like count for the respective post using SIZE(()-[: LIKED]->(d) ) -- this will give me total like count, as we are using unwind.

Comment: @AmitSharma `RETURN p as posts, SIZE(()-[:LIKED]->(p)) as likes LIMIT 25` UNWIND just converts a list value into a column value, so after UNWIND, you would just return the data you want as normal.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with an optional variable-length relationship, which can be achieved by using a lower bound of 0:

```
MATCH (me:User {UserId: '39434e4d-d501-4fba-8aae-16cf652deb3e'})-[:FOLLOWSS*0..1]->(f:User)-[:CREATED]-(p:Posts) 
RETURN p LIMIT 25
```

The `[:FOLLOWSS*0..1]` is the key, as this means that it will include patterns that have the :FOLLOWSS relationship to another :User node, as well as patterns where no relationship is traversed (meaning your `me` user is the same node as the `f` :User node).

Comment: I made a small correction with the existing query, sorry for the inconvenience.I removed -[fc:CREATED]-

Answer (score 1):

Building up on [@InverseFalcon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92359/inversefalcon)'s answer, here is a query that returns data in embedded collections :

```
MATCH (n:User {name:"ikwattro"})<-[:FOLLOWS*0..1]-(x)-[:CREATED]->(p:Post)
RETURN n, 
[x IN collect(p) WHERE (n)-[:CREATED]->(x) | x.title] AS userPosts, 
[x IN collect(p) WHERE NOT (n)-[:CREATED]->(x) | x.title] AS followersPosts


╒═══════════════════╤═══════════╤═════════════════════════╕
│"n"                │"userPosts"│"followersPosts"         │
╞═══════════════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"ikwattro"}│["Post1"]  │["Post4","Post3","Post2"]│
└───────────────────┴───────────┴─────────────────────────┘
```